# Please help me with 32bit libs for 64 bit

Tags: games

How i can fix this problem with "Portal"? I have only used Ubuntu for a few days (Ubuntu 14.04).

```
AppFramework : Unable to load module vguimatsurface.so!
Unable to load interface VGUI_Surface030 from vguimatsurface.so
```

Comment: I not have Steam. I will download game from torrent. And i found fix for my trouble!`Go to Settings - Software and Updates - Other Software, click add and write deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse, for next run terminal and say him "sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install ia32-libs"`

Comment: The `vguimatsurface.so` library is located inside the tree of portal. However it requires some 32-bit libraries to run. You can check which libraries are not found with `ldd bin/vguimatsurface.so`. In my case I needed to install several libraries from source to get the right version.

Answer (score 4):

## Background

---

I managed to solve this issue and run Counter Strike: Source by installing Ubuntu's i386 versions of libs [mentioned on ArchLinux forum by buhman](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1380048#p1380048).

## Solution

---

Run following command in Terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install fontconfig:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxi6:i386 libnss3:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpng3:i386 libasound2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsdl2-gfx-1.0-0:i386 libgcrypt11:i386
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That worked to solve the same problem in different Valve's game. Too bad, I can't accept the solution (it is not my question).

Comment: worked on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Half-Life2 and Ubuntu 22.04.1, Jammy:

```
cd ~/Games/Half-Life_2/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin ldd bin/vguimatsurface.so | grep 'not'
```

check which library is missing. In my case:

`libpng12.so.0 => not found`

I had to build this from the source and needed `x86` version, my machine is `x86_64`. So, let's cross compile:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib-i686-linux-gnu
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev:i386

mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
wget https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz
tar Jxvf libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz
cd libpng-1.2.54/
CC="i686-linux-gnu-gcc" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

`libpng12` library is now installed in `/usr/local/lib`

To run the game:

```
cd ~/Games/Half-Life_2/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./hl2.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In steam option just type :

```
optirun -b primus %command% -windowed -nojoy
```

Comment: He didn't even say that he's using optirun or Steam...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to install the ia-32libs. To do that on later versions of Ubuntu, just enter the following commands one after the another and you are done!!

---

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers indicate, you need `ia32-libs`.

For Ubuntu 14.04 there is a small trick you need to use to install ia32-libs:

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" > ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23194339/3494126